# React handle form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to create a form in React/Redux. For now I just want the form to trigger my function handleSubmit when the form is submitted. However at the moment it looks like the function is triggered instantly on page load ...

```
export default class AssetsAdd extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this)
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    if (this.refs.titleInput !== '') {
      event.preventDefault();
      var asset = {
        date: '',
        title : this.refs.titleInput.value,
        id : '',
        type: this.refs.typeInput.value
      }

      return this.props.dispatch(addAsset(asset))
    }


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
          <Portlet title='New Asset' form>
            <Form horizontal onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label text='Title' size='3' />
                <Input ref="titleInput" placeholder='Enter asset title' size='4'/>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label text='Type' size='3' />
                <Input ref="typeInput" placeholder='Enter asset type' size='4'/>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label text='Description' size='3' />
                <Input ref="descriptionInput" placeholder='Enter asset description' size='4'/>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label text='Documentation' size='3' />
                <Input ref="documentationInput" placeholder='Enter documentation URL' size='4'/>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormActionBar>
                <SubmitButton value='Submit'/>
                <CancelButton value='Cancel'/>
              </FormActionBar>
            </Form>
          </Portlet>
        </Row>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    assets: state.assets
  };
}

export const AssetAddContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(AssetsAdd);
```

I know the rest of the code isn't all correct yet but my main concern now is just getting the onSubmit action triggered at the right moment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like you're not binding your `handleSubmit`.

From [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html):

> Methods follow the same semantics as regular ES6 classes, meaning that
>   they don't automatically bind this to the instance.

You've got three options

1. Add a constructor and do the binding there (recommended):

   `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);`
2. Bind directly:

   `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}`
3. Use arrow `=>` functions

   `onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit}`

Comment: 2 first ones are working but the 3rd option is not working. It should be like this:
onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit()}

Comment: but the event is not passed in?

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the `handleSubmit` as a prop

```
 <SubmitButton value='Submit' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
```

Then assign that prop to the button on the render function  of the SubmmitButton component.

```
// submmit button component @render method

<button onClick={this.props.onSubmit} >Submit</button>
```

Comment: [Note that submit is fired only on the form element, not the button or submit input. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit). So you shouldn't put `onSubmit` on the button.

Comment: This was just a name fort the property

Comment: The point is that your suggestion completely by-passes the `onsubmit` event of the form element.