# Conflicting events: onKeyPress & onClick

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a from like this:

[image]

With the following code:

```
<form onKeyPress={this.login.bind(this)}>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
    <button type="button" onClick={this.login.bind(this)}>Log In</button>
</form>
```

While I have the `login()` method like below:

```
login(e){
    if((e.type==='keypress' && e.which===13) || e.type==='click'){        
            //Do login operations:
            this.props.store.login()//the method inside MobX store
    }
}
```

On following scenarios, there is no errors and I can login:

1. I click on the `login` button with mouse
2. I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the login button is NOT focused

But the following 3rd scenario, gives me errors due to the login operations being called twice:

3. When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> while login button IS focused (for example login button is focused by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> key)

I wonder what is the best practice by which I can avoid the errors of 3rd scenario. I looked through other related SO questions but I couldn't figure out the best practice.

---

I forgot to mention I'm using ReactJS with MobX.

Comment: Please tag the question with the framework you use. The way to handle submit on click and on enter is to ONLY bind the submit and have a submit button

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, I added ReactJS and MobX tags

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262148/react-handle-form-submit

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, I'm looking over the question and its answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by moving `onKeyPress` attribute from `<form>` tag to text-type `<input>` tags:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" onKeyPress={this.login.bind(this)}/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" onKeyPress={this.login.bind(this)}/>
    <button type="button" onClick={this.login.bind(this)}>Log In</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `onSubmit` event if it suits your use case better:

**Example ([JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/kugewijuwu/edit?js,console,output))**

```
class App extends Component {
  login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('login');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.login}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
        <button type="submit">Log In</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```